# How to pass unicode string from C++ to delphi?

Tags: c++, delphi

Ive found many topics about passing from Delphi to C++ but still confused about.

```
std::string s1(" look  here ");
```

What is the correct way to pass it to a delphi code?

none of this is not working, producing wrong chars

```
char * s = (char *)s1.c_str();
Call_Delphi_func(s);
.......
Memo1.Lines.Add(UTF8String(PChar(pointer(s))));
```

Comment: Have you tried `std::string s1(u8" look  here ");`?  It's possible you're running into source encoding issues and `s1` doesn't end up encoded as UTF-8 if you don't explicitly tell the compiler it should be.  You could also explicitly specify the bytes to use: `std::string s1(" look \xF0\x9F\x91\x86 here ");`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did not say which version of Delphi you are using, but the fact that you use `UTF8String` the way you are implies that you are using Delphi 2009 or later. If so, `PChar` is `PWideChar` (`wchar_t*` in C and C++). Use `PAnsiChar` (`char*` in C and C++) explicitly instead, and get rid of your unnecessary `Pointer` typecast:

```cpp
std::string s1 = u8" look  here ";
char * s = const_cast<char*>(s1.c_str());
Delphi_func(s);
```

```pascal
procedure Delphi_func(s: PAnsiChar); stdcall;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(UTF8String(s));
end;
```

Alternatively, use `std::wstring` with `PWideChar` instead:

```cpp
std::wstring s1 = L" look  here ";
wchar_t * s = const_cast<wchar_t*>(s1.c_str());
Delphi_func(s);
```

```pascal
procedure Delphi_func(s: PWideChar); stdcall;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
end;
```